# How to animate opencart dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, opencart, dropdown, opencart2.x

So, I am working on my ecommerce with opencart and I wanted to make the dropdown menu to show with an animation, a simple one.
The problem is that I apply the transition, but it doesn't work.
The code part is this one

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I am usign version 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `.dropdown-menu` has `display:none` style in bootstrap, you can't animate it with pure css without overriding, you can animate it this way:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block; /* Override the bootstrap display: none */
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Another example:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block; /* Override the bootstrap display: none */
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 200%;
}
#menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
}
```

note: don't edit bootstrap files, add above code at the end of your theme's stylesheet: `stylesheet.css`